# Python's MySQLdb slow! using 'SSCurso'r vs PHP's 'mysql_fetch_assoc'

Tags: php, python, mysql-python

I need to go over an entire table in Python.
I am using MySQLdb via 'SSCursor' and it is much slower than PHP's stuff.

**PHP 5.3.5**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anytable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
#do stuff

}
```

**Python2.7**

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM anytable")
for row in cursor:
    pass
```

**RESULTS**

PHP: **5 seconds** CPU around 35%, 
Python: **25 seconds** CPU 100%

Does MySQLdb just suck or am I doing something wrong?
If MySQLdb, what can I use instead for better performance/same functionality?

Comment: yes, all the relevant, this obviously excludes the connection

Comment: Did you print out all the data to ensure both are returning the same results. (Highly unlikely this would be an issue, but doesn't hurt to check.)

Comment: @MichaelMior - printing all the data would be exactly the cause of the problem. I hope it is so. (see my answer bellow)

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing python results to stdout? 
Because I'd expect around this kind of difference in performance if you ARE printing all the data to stdout (the console). PHP code normally is run without stdout output to the console. The problem is that outputing to the console involves the computer having to draw and move around milions of pixels as text scrolls by the window in real time.

If it is not that, than it looks like MySQLdb is indeed sucking, and you should put in more information so people could find a work around to optmize things for you.

Comment: Do you have any results which suggest PHP console output is slower? "PHP code is normally run without stdout output to the console." doesn't mean anything wrt performance.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) module. You can optimize your quires, for better memory and cpu usage.

**Reference**: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html

Comment: SQLAlchemy is great, but won't do better than hand-written queries by a knowledgeable DBA.

Comment: Umm it can.. . Lets say you have 'x' rows to fetch.. . Now using, MySQLDb you can fetch all 'x' rows together or 'x/2' rows by making two quires but using SQLAlchemy you can configure it to populate your code with one row at a time.. . thus kinda reducing load on your cpu .. .

Comment: How does this reduce CPU load? If you need all the rows, you're going to fetch them eventually.

Comment: Actually we are dividing the load and memory usage over time .. . In practical situation, let say we need to fetch 1M rows.. . An Amazon EC2 small would hang.. . Reason out of buffer memory.. . But same would not happen using SQL Alchmey.. . Reason is balancing the load.. . Moreover, time consumption would not be multiplicative, thus a time efficiency of around 60 - 70% can be achieved .. . N this is the reason why companies as big as Wize etc uses SQL Alchemy.. . ;)

Comment: I can't really imagine an scenario where I would want to fetch 1M rows, but it's true that could cause problems. But if I was writing SQL by hand, then I wouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: When you are into development of real systems, I am sure you dont do your queries manually (by hand).. . Anyways, if you are concerned about low load on big machines I am sure little time differences wont make a much of a difference.. .